# HttpPost works on Android's SDK 8, but not SDK 17

Tags: java, android, json, http, sdk

When I insert SDK 17 into the manifest file, nothing works (it does not load). But when I insert SDK 8, it works.

```
private void loadq(){
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://iwindroids.ru/app/fla/getq");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        InputStream inputStream = null;String result = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){sb.append(line + "\n");}
            result = sb.toString();
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            String t = jObject.getString("t").replace("--", "—");
            String a = jObject.getString("a");
            //String i = jObject.getString("i");
            TextView et = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            EditText at = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            et.setText(t+".");
            at.setText(a);
            live();
            showTimer();
        } catch (Exception e){}
        finally {try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}}
    }
```

Thank You!

Comment: What error exactly do you get? Can you constantly reproduce it on SDK 17 and constantly run the same code with success on SDK 8?

Comment: Just when I insert SDK 8, in "a" appears in the loaded text "t" when I insert SDK 17, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Look in the LogCat to see it. You have to place your code in an AsyncTask or thread.